# kafka-node ready event is not getting triggered

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using kafka-node npm module ,0.2.27 version.
 I found `producer.on('ready',fn(){})` is never getting called. 
When I inspected producer object, observed it is as follows

```
{ ready: true,
  client: 
   { connectionString: '10.196.160.100.:2181,10.196.160.150:2181,10.196.160.151:2181',
     clientId: 'dev',
     zkOptions: { sessionTimeOut: 10000, spinDelay: 1000, retries: 10 },
     brokers: 
      { 'custom-kafka.mine.com:9092': [Object],
        'custom-storm.mine.com:9092': [Object] },
     longpollingBrokers: {},
     topicMetadata: {},
     topicPartitions: {},
     correlationId: 0,
     cbqueue: {},
     brokerMetadata: { '0': [Object], '1': [Object] },
     ready: true,
     zk: { client: [Object], _events: [Object], inited: true },
     _events: { ready: [Object], error: [Object], close: [Object] } },
  requireAcks: 1,
  ackTimeoutMs: 100,
  _events: {} }
```

Instead of waiting for on ('ready') event, I just checked `if(producer.ready)` and I am able to publish to kafka with a little timeout.
 Ideally, event should be triggered.
 I am not sure whether I am taking the right approach.
 Any pointers in this direction is greatly appreciated.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Producer = kafka.Producer,
    client = new kafka.Client('192.168.50.252:2181'),
    producer = new Producer(client),
    payloads = [
        { 
            topic: 'test topic', 
            messages: ['test message'] 
        }
    ];

    client.on('ready', function (){
        console.log('client ready');
    })  

    client.on('error', function (err){
        console.log('client error: ' + err);
    })  

    producer.on('ready', function () {
        producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
            console.log('send: ' + data);        
            process.exit();
        });
    });

    producer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
        process.exit();
    });
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I am having a similar code. However, the issue is "ready" event is not getting triggered. i found zookeeper and kafka are up and running

Comment: Could you try putting some extra code in to check the client is connecting OK - I've added some to the example above - this will confirm that the client is connecting to Zookeeper OK

Comment: The ready event will only be fired once. It is possible it is firing but you are missing it.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue too and your approach I believe is the right one. 
See the ready event of the producer is fired only once, when the constructor of the producer is called. After the producer.ready property is set to true.
Since I believe like me, you also were calling the constructor in some other place and returning or exporting the producer from there, it means, that ready event won't be fired in the place where you're actually calling producer.send()

Instead, using

```
`if(producer.ready){
    producer.send(payloads, function(err,res){
            console.log(res)
    });
 }        
`
```

Hope this helps.